# SQL - How to Calculate Account Balances in Gnucash?

Tags: sql, finance, gnucash

**Title:** How to Calculate Account Balances in Gnucash with Recursive SQL

**Hello Stack Overflow Community,**

I've been using Gnucash for a year and recently attempted to create custom reports for my financial data. However, I encountered a challenge while trying to calculate the cumulative values of accounts, including their sub-accounts.

**Database Schema:**

I'm working with the following tables in my Gnucash database:
(https://piecash.readthedocs.io/en/master/_images/schema.png)

- 'accounts'
- Columns: guid, name, account_type, commodity_guid, commodity_scu, non_std_scu, parent_guid, code, description, hidden, placeholder
- Example data provided:

| guid | name | account_type | commodity_guid | commodity_scu | non_std_scu | parent_guid | code | description | hidden | placeholder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1fb9d8623ae04501a62b71dd0d5f1f8d | Root Account | ROOT |  | 0 | 0 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 |
| 7c222beb8a7c439399d1ac4850ba09fb | Accruals | ASSET | dbf3687850b3411a8b548d48a6e961ee | 100 | 0 | 681fe705237c4ba39026ac7ab5b48b58 | 1.3 |  | 0 | 0 |
| b3f3021120954d1e83c651e6de131e0b | Accounts Receivable | ASSET | dbf3687850b3411a8b548d48a6e961ee | 100 | 0 | 681fe705237c4ba39026ac7ab5b48b58 | 1.2 |  | 0 | 0 |
| 12ffda3963ab46d4b8f95635c3a1debe | Liabilities | LIABILITY | dbf3687850b3411a8b548d48a6e961ee | 100 | 0 | 1fb9d8623ae04501a62b71dd0d5f1f8d | 2 |  | 0 | 0 |
| 3ee7b0171d9b4b76aae67e701ae3ed0e | Accounts Payable | LIABILITY | dbf3687850b3411a8b548d48a6e961ee | 100 | 0 | 12ffda3963ab46d4b8f95635c3 |  |  |  |  |

- 'transactions'
- Columns: guid, currency_guid, num, post_date, enter_date, description
- Example data provided

| guid | currency_guid | num | post_date | enter_date | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e7a4c802ca2b4f90a167e3376199ad97 | dbf3687850b3411a8b548d48a6e961ee |  | ########## | ########## | Openin Balance - Wallet |
| 387f19734c9042f982f023b754b55fe2 | dbf3687850b3411a8b548d48a6e961ee |  | ########## | ########## | Public Transport |
| 057ce32f70d44ccdbb043aaa3fa6a54f | dbf3687850b3411a8b548d48a6e961ee |  | ########## | ########## | Water |
| 59c8e5fa1a9b45cea20fe1b5453e7743 | dbf3687850b3411a8b548d48a6e961ee |  | ########## | ########## | Income - Gift |
| 2e34c3b14e464144a30690a7b3ab873e | dbf3687850b3411a8b548d48a6e961ee |  | ########## | ########## | Junk Food |

- 'splits'
- Columns: guid, tx_guid, account_guid, memo, action, reconcile_state, reconcile_date, value_num, value_denom, quantity_num, quantity_denom, lot_guid
- Example data provided:

| guid | tx_guid | account_guid | memo | action | reconcile_state | reconcile_date | value_num | value_denom | quantity_num | quantity_denom | lot_guid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4c8e31391a994309835ccf22041716b7 | e7a4c802ca2b4f90a167e3376199ad97 | a35d4345406045189f726a23a4d9f6be |  |  | n | ########## | 2000 | 100 | 2000 | 100 |  |
| 96bc3cb0d8a140468d672f8fe6f37ab4 | e7a4c802ca2b4f90a167e3376199ad97 | 1652d2056e9f423c95d187614f60be3e |  |  | n | ########## | -2000 | 100 | -2000 | 100 |  |
| bdd077bbcc0d44d78059b8ac32f07032 | 387f19734c9042f982f023b754b55fe2 | 7e71a62c60a1493b9660a35ed287a968 |  |  | n | ########## | 1000 | 100 | 1000 | 100 |  |
| 5088a553afbb478e8367a5d751746200 | 387f19734c9042f982f023b754b55fe2 | a35d4345406045189f726a23a4d9f6be |  |  | n | ########## | -1000 | 100 | -1000 | 100 |  |
| d4a62d10713e4c45b58e35c52f707a7f | 057ce32f70d44ccdbb043aaa3fa6a54f | 47131155460843279406277871f98d6e |  |  | n | ########## | 500 | 100 | 500 | 100 |  |

**My Goal:**

I aim to generate financial reports that summarize the account balances, including sub-accounts. The desired outcome can be visualized as shown in this image:
(https://ibb.co/jyPzpXY)

**Challenges:**

I attempted to achieve this using the following recursive SQL query:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE AccountHierarchy AS
    (SELECT a.guid,
            a.parent_guid,
            a.code,
            a.name,
            0 AS level,
            SUM(COALESCE(s.value_num, 0)) as value_num
     FROM accounts a
     LEFT JOIN splits s ON a.guid = s.account_guid
     WHERE parent_guid IS NULL
     GROUP BY a.guid,
              a.parent_guid,
              a.code,
              a.name
     UNION ALL SELECT a2.guid,
                      a2.parent_guid,
                      a2.code,
                      a2.name,
                      ah.level + 1 AS level,
                      SUM(COALESCE(s2.value_num, 0)) + SUM(ah.value_num) AS value_num
     FROM accounts AS a2
     JOIN AccountHierarchy AS ah ON a2.parent_guid = ah.guid
     LEFT JOIN splits s2 ON a2.guid = s2.account_guid
     GROUP BY a2.guid,
              a2.parent_guid,
              a2.code,
              a2.name,
              ah.level)
SELECT guid,
       parent_guid,
       level,
       code,
       name
FROM AccountHierarchy
WHERE parent_guid IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY code,
         level,
         name;
```

However, I encountered an error:

```
ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in a recursive query's recursive term
```

**Question:**

How can I modify my SQL query or approach to successfully calculate the account balances, including their sub-accounts, as shown in the desired query image? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to help me overcome this challenge.

Thank you in advance!

---

This revised version of your question provides a clear and concise description of your issue, includes relevant details, and presents the problem you're facing. It also mentions your desired outcome and the specific error you encountered, making it suitable for Stack Overflow.